# Java: Good candidate for key to use with HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have declared following HashMap

`Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>(); // Java 6+`

I have two questions :
**A)** Is there any **Issue(Performance or Other)** , while I put element in HashMap with **primitive data** type for above declare HashMap
for example

```
map.put(1,"abc");
```

Or I have to use only

```
map.put(new Integer(1),"abc");
```

**B)** Which is good candidate for HashMap if I have number(int) as a Key
   **String OR Integer**

Comment: You can't use generics with primitives. You'll end up with `Integer` either way due to autoboxing. In fact, autoboxing *might* be faster because you won't always allocate a `new Integer()`; you can negate this advantage by using `Integer.valueOf()` instead of `new Integer()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use any one but the important thing is key should preferably not be mutable as this can cause aberrant behavior.

Java HashMap relies on two things:

- the hashCode() method, which returns an integer that is generated
  from the key and used inside the map
- the equals(..) method, which should be consistent to the hash
  calculated, this means that if two keys has the same hashcode than it
  is desiderable that they are the same element.

So if you are planning to use just simple types as keys (like you said integers or strings) just don't worry, there's no difference. In both cases two different items will have the same hashcode.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
Integer.valueOf(1)
```

instead of using the new keyword. Java stores values -128 thru 127 in a IntegerCache, and will return the already allocated value from the heap.

As for primitive v/s Integer object, java internally [autoboxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) both ways, so it will not make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is effectively the same. Java is using auto boxing to convert

```
map.put(1,"abc");
```

to

```
map.put(Integer.valueOf(1),"abc");
```

during compile time.

If you need better performace, look at external libraries supporting primivites as key in maps.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the `map.put(1,"abc");`, the java compiler internally uses the `Integer.valueOf(8)` method

As for the performance question, I suggest you refer to [String as key in hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029983/string-as-key-in-hashmap)